# How to create a column where the first value is equal to the second value of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a column where the first element is equal to the second element of another column for the same ID.The last date will be a default value.

For example, I have this table:

| ID | start_date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 03/04/2022 |
| 123 | 06/04/2022 |
| 123 | 08/05/2022 |
| 123 | 10/05/2022 |
| 123 | 15/05/2022 |
| 123 | 20/05/2022 |

I want to get this output:

| ID | start_date | end_date. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 03/04/2022 | 06/04/2022 |
| 123 | 06/04/2022 | 08/05/2022 |
| 123 | 08/05/2022 | 10/05/2022 |
| 123 | 10/05/2022 | 15/05/2022 |
| 123 | 15/05/2022 | 20/05/2022 |
| 123 | 20/05/2022 | 01/01/1999 |

I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: Look at the lead() function

Comment: yep its the one i have used on the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this is the query that answers your question (disregard my date format and use yours):

```
declare @fixeddate date
set @fixeddate='12/12/2024'

select Id, start_date, ISNULL(end_date, @fixeddate) end_date
from (
    select id,            
           start_date,
           lead(start_date) over (partition by id order by id) as end_date
    from test
) as t;
```

You can also check the fiddle i have created [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e33a9/2)

Comment: yes indeed COALESCE works on several DBMS however ISNULL performs better in OPs scenario

Comment: Thanks Jonas i have updated the fiddle, feel free to give it a try and if it looks ok :)